# ¿Cómo puedo retornar varias líneas de código dentro de una función?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente función:

```
function ponerFecha() {
    $("#fecha_estipulada_root").attr({
        "class":"picker picker--opened picker--focused",
        "aria-hidden":"false"
     });

    $("#fecha_estipulada").attr({
        "class":"atepic picker__input picker__input--target picker__input--active",
        "aria-expanded":true
     });

    $("[aria-controls*='fecha_estipulada_table']")
         .attr("disabled",false);
return;
}
```

Pero no estoy seguro que me ejecute todo con el "return" sólo, o sí es posible.

Gracias.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Quieres que te retorne algo, o quieres que hago algo y luego retorne sin nada? [Una pequeña dosis de documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/return) no vendría mal para aclararse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, en este caso que expones, aunque tengas o no el `return`, cuando ejecutes la función `ponerFecha()` se hará lo que dentro tienes implementado. De todas formas la pregunta no se comprende bien sobre que deseas hacer, si retornar esas 3 líneas anteriores al return o solo ejecutar la función.